# are maven dependency exclusions necessary when using spring (mvc) + hadoop + hive?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, hadoop

I have a web app working great. Tried to connect to hadoop using hive. Tests work fine, but I can't run the web app.  I get an error from transitive maven dependencies on hadoop-core bringing in j2ee jars that override Tomcat and mess up when trying to run the web app (specifically in loading the context).

Foolishly I thought maybe if I just use Spring Data built for CDH5 they would have covered all that. No such luck. I was following their docs here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/wiki/Build-with-Cloudera-CDH5

Here's my current POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4.RELEASE-cdh5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${hive.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.<init>(Validator.java:515)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1817)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
```

I also got this error when building direct from cloudera's repos

I could start stuffing exclusions in there, but that feels hacky, and I'm paranoid about other transitive dependency errors cropping up that I may not know about.

I've pored over the docs and the sample code and pom files here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/blob/master/hive/pom.xml

They don't seem to have exclusions in their POM files. However, I've seen other people do it, such as here: [Spring + Maven + Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704861/spring-maven-hadoop)

Is that the accepted way to work with these technologies? This is my first time so am seeking some confirmation here. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Is it canonical to simply have exclusions

Comment: Looks like your runtime has an older version of the Servlet API than the library needs. What version of Tomcat, and can you upgrade it?

Comment: Ah, I shouldn't have said Tomcat. I'm using STS with Pivotal tc Server 2.9, which I believe is similar to Tomcat 7. It's very new. So I don't think the version is too old. I'd wager the servlet api in the hadoop transitive dependency is older and conflicting. Adding the exclusions from the Spring + Maven + Hadoop article worked. But, like I said, trying to figure out how this is usually done. That seems hacky to me. Maybe that's just accepted.